# How can I do a jest test in this function in React axios?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, moxios

I guys I created a service in React and I need to test this part of the service, I'm using axios and Jest to do this.
I have the next code in React :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Endpoints from './endpoints';
const baseUrl = Endpoints.getBackendEndpoint();

export const validateName =  (nameObject, callback) => {
 axios.post(`${baseUrl}/validateName`, {...nameObject})
   .then(response =>{ 
      response.data
    })
   .then(data => callback(data));
};
```

I don't need return the promise because all the work is doing by the `callback()` function.

This is the code that I have in Jest:

```
mport moxios from 'moxios';
import * as service from '../service';
import mockResponses from './service.test.json';
import Endpoints from '../endpoints';


const validateObjName = {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Bob',
  }

beforeEach(() => {
const baseUrl = Endpoints.getBackendEndpoint();
  moxios.stubRequest(
    `${baseUrl}/validateName`,
    { ...validateObjName },
    {
      status: 200,
      response: mockResponses.validateForm,
    }
  );
});

afterEach(() => {
  moxios.uninstall();
});

it('validateName()', () => {
   service.validateName(validateObjName, jest.fn());
});
```

It works, but still need to increase the Branch coverage.

Thanks for you help guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get code coverage the code has to run **while a test is running** so you will want to return the `Promise` so you can `await` it in your test so the `then` callbacks run **during your test**.

Also, you can simplify `validateName` to this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Endpoints from './endpoints';
const baseUrl = Endpoints.getBackendEndpoint();

export const validateName = (nameObject, callback) => {
  return axios.post(`${baseUrl}/validateName`, { ...nameObject })
    .then(response => callback(response.data));
};
```

In your test you need to install `moxios` in your `beforeEach` and pass the mock response as the second parameter to `moxios.stubRequest`.

Then use an `async` test function and `await` the `Promise` returned by `validateName`:

```
import moxios from 'moxios';
import * as service from '../service';
import mockResponses from './service.test.json';
import Endpoints from '../endpoints';

const validateObjName = {
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'Bob',
}

beforeEach(() => {
  moxios.install();  // install moxios
  const baseUrl = Endpoints.getBackendEndpoint();
  moxios.stubRequest(
    `${baseUrl}/validateName`,
    {
      status: 200,
      response: mockResponses.validateForm
    }
  );  // response is the second argument
});

afterEach(() => {
  moxios.uninstall();
});

it('validateName()', () => {
  service.validateName(validateObjName, jest.fn());
});

it('validateName()', async () => {  // use an async test function
  const spy = jest.fn();
  await service.validateName(validateObjName, spy);  // await the Promise
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockResponses.validateForm);  // Success!
});
```

That should give you a working test and 100% code coverage.